# Heroku + mongoose connection error: no primary server found in set

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, replication, mongoose

I have a mongodb replica set on mongolab.

I'm using nodejs + mongoose. When I'm trying to connect from my local machine everything goes ok. 
But after deployment to heroku something wrong happens and mongoose got strange error:

```
[Error: no primary server found in set]
```

Here some code (server.js):

```
async.series([
  function(callback){
    console.log('DB Connection: ' + siteConf.mongo_url);
    mongoose.connect(siteConf.mongo_url, siteConf.mongo_options, callback);
  },      
  function(callback){
    http.createServer(app).listen(siteConf.port, callback);
  }
],
function(err, results){

 if (err) {
   console.log(err);
 }

 console.log('Running in ' + (process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development') + ' mode @ ' + siteConf.uri);
  }
);
```

This url I'm using as connection string:

```
mongodb://username:password@someid-a0.mongolab.com:39897/pm_prod,mongodb://someid-a1.mongolab.com:39897
```

The main thing I can't understand is: what is the differences between my maching and heroku cloud hosting.

I already tried to remove node_modules and npm install them to be sure that I have same versions as on heroku. (Because heroku do this on each deploy).

Thanks, and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Not sure if I could guide you to a technical solution but sharing a similar experience of problems with Heroku might help. MongoHQ was used for the database. The local machine + local MongoDB, local machine + MongoHQ interface worked perfect. Heroku + MongoHQ gave errors and the logs were not very helpful. Spent a few days trouble shooting. Except for basic support, Heroku is $1000 a month; can't afford. Shifted to AWS and have had no issues so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a URI problem. The format for DB URIs is:

```
mongodb://<user>:<pass>@host:port,host:port,...,host:port/db_name
```

That means that

```
mongodb://username:password@someid-a0.mongolab.com:39897/pm_prod,mongodb://someid-a1.mongolab.com:39897
```

should be:

```
mongodb://username:password@someid-a0.mongolab.com:39897,someid-a1.mongolab.com:39897/pm_prod
```

It's also worth noting for others: **If you are using Heroku's MongoLab add-on**, your URI is available as an environment variable at process.env.MONGOLAB_URI, so you don't have to place the URI in your code.

This could also be related to a running question about connectivity between Heroku and Mongo. See https://github.com/jcottr/temps-mort, which references two tickets for the Node Mongo driver:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-4

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-5

Comment: This is probably an answer. I'm waiting for patch in mongodb driver which should be released soon. (Version 1.1.12).